# Strange strncpy, fgets behaviour

Tags: c, stdin, fgets, strncpy

I'm basically writing the code to reading things that store the rest of the string if it starts with an l. Here is my code so far:

```
char input[80];
char fileName[80];

fgets(input, 80, stdin);   //Need to use because only want to read maximum 80 characters

if(input[0] == 'l') {
    printf("String length: %d\n", strlen(input));
    printf("String input: %s", input);
    strncpy(fileName, &input[1], (strlen(input)) -2);
    fileName[strlen(input)-1] = '\0';
    printf("Filename to save: %s \n", fileName);
}
```

When I input ljudyjudyjudyjudy
the filename I get when I printf is judyjudyjudyjudyH

It works sometimes with different inputs, but sometimes extra characters prop up?

Comment: `fileName[strlen(input)-1] = '\0';` why you take here length of `input` instead `filename`? It should be length of `filename`.

Comment: @Jayesh -- because `strncpy` is not guaranteed to NUL terminate the output string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are off by one:

```
fgets(input, 80, stdin);   //Need to use because only want to read maximum 80 characters

if(input[0] == 'l') {
    printf("String length: %d\n", strlen(input));
    printf("String input: %s", input);
    strncpy(fileName, &input[1], (strlen(input)) -2);
    fileName[strlen(input)-2] = '\0'; // should be -2 instead
    printf("Filename to save: %s \n", fileName);
}
```

In your example with `"ljudyjudyjudyjudy"` as input, you want to set `fileName[16]` to `'\0'` rather than `fileName[17]`.

Comment: yes, just did some more fiddling, and it seems that was the case, but wasn't sure why the original code would work with some input!

Comment: @user3603183 The reason why the original code sometimes works will involve the way you initialized `fileName`. If you include its declaration in your question, we can address that too.

Comment: @user3603183 Ah, if you default-initialize `char fileName[80] = {};` then you don't have to modify `filename` any further after the `strncpy`.